# Application redirection using data scheme in android not working from default browser

Tags: android

I am trying to redirect to my application from default browser. It is working fine with Firefox. While I am trying to redirect from chrome or default browser, it is not redirecting.
It is showing as "`Webpage is not available`"

Below is the intent filter for redirection I am using.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="launchApp"></data>
    <data android:host="*"></data>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

When I am calling from the Firefox as "`launchApp://`", it is redirecting to my application, but it is not the same with chrome or with the default browser.

Kindly do the needful

Thanks in advance